# How to use SortBy()

Tags: javascript, json, sorting

So I fetched data from

https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/earth/assets?lon=-112.097796&lat=36.098592&begin=2014-06-01&api_key=9Jz6tLIeJ0yY9vjbEUWaH9fsXA930J9hspPchute by using:

```
var data = JSON.parse(body);
```

but if you take a look, the dates near the end are not chronological. How do I use sortBy() to make sure the dates are in order?

```js
{
  "count": 56,
  "results": [{
    "date": "2014-06-05T18:02:51",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014156LGN01"
  }, {
    "date": "2014-06-21T18:02:55",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014172LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2014-07-07T18:03:03",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014188LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2014-07-23T18:03:05",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014204LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2014-08-08T18:03:14",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014220LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2014-08-24T18:03:17",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014236LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2014-09-09T18:03:21",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014252LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2014-09-25T18:03:18",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014268LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2014-10-11T18:03:25",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014284LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2014-10-27T18:03:23",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014300LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2014-11-12T18:03:26",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014316LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2014-11-28T18:03:24",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014332LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2014-12-14T18:03:18",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014348LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2014-12-30T18:03:14",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014364LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2015-01-15T18:03:14",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015015LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2015-01-31T18:03:10",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015031LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2015-02-16T18:03:01",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015047LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2015-03-04T18:02:56",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015063LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2015-03-20T18:02:46",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015079LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2015-04-05T18:02:35",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015095LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2015-04-21T18:02:34",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015111LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2015-05-07T18:02:18",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015127LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2015-05-23T18:02:16",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015143LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2015-06-08T18:02:26",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015159LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2015-06-24T18:02:32",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015175LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2015-07-10T18:02:43",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015191LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2015-07-26T18:02:49",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015207LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2015-08-11T18:02:53",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015223LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2015-08-27T18:03:00",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015239LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2015-09-12T18:03:07",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015255LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2015-09-28T18:03:13",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015271LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2015-10-14T18:03:13",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015287LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2015-10-30T18:03:19",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015303LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2015-11-15T18:03:19",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015319LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2015-12-01T18:03:21",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015335LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2015-12-17T18:03:21",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015351LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2016-01-02T18:03:18",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016002LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2016-01-18T18:03:18",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016018LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2016-02-03T18:03:15",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016034LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2016-02-19T18:03:06",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016050LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2016-03-06T18:03:05",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016066LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2016-03-22T18:02:58",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016082LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2016-04-07T18:02:50",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016098LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2016-04-23T18:02:43",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016114LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2016-05-09T18:02:46",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016130LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2016-05-25T18:02:50",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016146LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2016-06-10T18:02:54",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016162LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2016-06-26T18:03:01",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016178LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2016-07-12T18:03:09",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016194LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2016-07-28T18:03:13",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016210LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2016-08-13T18:03:15",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016226LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2016-08-29T18:03:23",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016242LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2016-09-14T18:03:26",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016258LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2016-09-30T18:03:27",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016274LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2016-04-30T18:08:59",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80380352016121LGN00"
  }, {
    "date": "2016-05-16T18:08:57",
    "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80380352016137LGN00"
  }]
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] - I added your object, but what did you try? For example search on "sort object date" - actually it is a duplicate easily found

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/sort-javascript-object-array-by-date